# Query mysql with three tables, one is relation table

Tags: php, sql, join

I'm still a SQL-rookie. I have three tables with a given structure:

```
table1 (products)
--------------------------------------
id   ident   title   types   desc
--------------------------------------
01   111ab   title1  2       details 1
02   222ab   title2  1       details 2
03   333ab   title3  2       details 3
```

A product can belong to many product-types. The "types"-column is the number of types related to a product. Product "111ab" belongs to 2 product-types.

```
table2 (product-types)
--------------------------
id   type    typedesc
--------------------------
01   type1   description 1
02   type2   description 2
03   type3   description 3


table3 (relations)
-------------------
id   tbl1id  tbl2id
-------------------
01   01      01
02   02      03
03   03      03
04   01      03
05   03      02
```

Table3 shows the relations between table1 (products) and table2 (product-types). Product "111ab" is related to the product-types "01" and "03".

I want to create a data-structure which should be something like this:

```
type-description    prod   title   desc
-------------------------------------------
type1-description1  111ab  title1  details1
type2-description2  333ab  title3  details3
type3-description3  111ab  title1  details1
type3-description3  222ab  title2  details2
type3-description3  333ab  title3  details3
```

This structure will end up in an assoc-array of product-types with the related products as assoc-sub-arrays, sorted by "ident" of table1:

```
type1 description1
        111ab title1 details1

type2 description2
        333ab title3 details3

type3 description3
        111ab title1 details1
        222ab title2 details2
        333ab title3 details3
```

This array will be json-encoded and sent as a query-result of an ajax-request.

I read the threads about JOINing tables here at stackoverflow but can not generate a working SELECT-structure. Maybe this can not be done by a single query. I don't know.

Please, can anyone give me a little help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an `INNER JOIN` will suffice your requirements,

```
SELECT  a.type, a.typedesc,
        c.ident, c.title,
        c.`desc`
FROM    `product-types` a
        INNER JOIN relations b
            ON a.id = b.tbl2id
        INNER JOIN products c
            ON b.tbl1id = c.id
ORDER BY a.type, a.typedesc
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12b79/3)

or

```
SELECT  CONCAT(a.type, '-',a.typedesc) `type-description`,
        c.ident, c.title,
        c.`desc`
FROM    `product-types` a
        INNER JOIN relations b
            ON a.id = b.tbl2id
        INNER JOIN products c
            ON b.tbl1id = c.id
ORDER BY `type-description`
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12b79/5)

Comment: Yes, works great. Result is as as needed. Thank you so much. Thanks for the Fiddle-link.